# Logging file are not generating

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, logging

I am facing problem in Log4j,like in my Maven Rest API project i have log4j.propeties file like below.

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootCategory= TRACE, stdout, file 

# Each package has different appender name 
log4j.logger.club.exbrain.hht.service.management=TRACE, club.exbrain.hht.service.management

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender

#Redirect to Tomcat logs folder
log4j.appender.file.File=${catalina.home}/logs/logging.log

log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=25MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Issue is When i am running tomcat server from Eclispe i am getting my all logs in tomcat logs folder but when i  export war file and deployed it to server i am getting warning message like below

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

Please tell where i can put this Log4j file or is there any possibilities is there to get the log

Comment: You can find the problem, when you (in detail) know the difference between your eclipse-server-runtime and your standalone-(server-)runtime. (compare logging.properties, catalina.properties, ...) ..it should work as supposed/as in eclipse!

Comment: in eclipse i manually added build path for resource folder  at that time it start working but war file how can i ?

Comment: ..in a normal maven-war-build: all of `src/main/resources` land in `/WEB-INF/classes` ..which is "normally" root/part of (a web container) class path...

Comment: in /WEB-INF/classes  i can find my Log4j.properties file but still it showing warning